# Is there a reference for this well-known inequality?

Tags: reference-request, integral-inequality

Here is the statement :

> Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^1([0,T],\mathbb{R}_+)$, $T>0$ such that : for all $t \in [0,T]$, $\displaystyle f(t) \le c + \int_{0}^{t} \eta(f(x))\mathrm{d}x$ where $\eta : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ is continuous, non-decreasing and checks $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\eta(s)}=+\infty$.
>
> $\bullet$ If $c=0$ then $f \equiv 0$.
>
> $\bullet$ If $c >0$ then for all $t \in [0,T]$, $\mathcal{M}(c)\le t + \mathcal{M}(f(t))$ with $\displaystyle \mathcal{M}(x)=\int_{x}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\eta(s)}$ .

I heard that this result could have been proved by Yudovich but I did not find anything relevant about it.

So if anyone has references about this statement, it would be nice to share.

**Edit** : I managed to find the following statement which I guess generalizes the previous one :

[image]

However I still found nothing about Yudovich's result...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Your result appears to be a special case of the [Bihari-LaSalle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihari%E2%80%93LaSalle_inequality), which generalizes to the analogous problem $$f(t)\leq c+\int_0^t{\eta(f(s))\cdot v(s)\,ds}$$ when integrating against measures other than Lebesgue.

As of writing, the linked Wikipedia article only cites LaSalle and Bihari's original papers.

The only missing case is when $c=0$, but that can be seen by taking a pointwise limit.

Comment: Thank you ! I managed to find in the literature a result called Osgood's lemma which is very similar to yours but supposing local integrability !